# Rails 4.0.4: How do I display whether or not the creation of a record was successful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

So After submitting a form for my `Testimony` model I get the following activity in my rails console:

```
Processing by TestimoniesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Y7n/+rlDoH3ys68HMOh6T6WFpAelRT18WUPstCz41vE=",  "testimony"=>{"first_name"=>"bob ", "last_name"=>"balaban", "email"=>"", "contact_number"=>"", "country"=>"", "question1"=>"", "question2"=>"", "question3"=>"", "question4"=>"", "question5"=>"", "signature"=>"", "waiver"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Save Testimony"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Testimony Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "testimonies" WHERE ("testimonies"."last_name" =    'balaban' AND "testimonies"."first_name" = 'bob ' AND "testimonies"."email" = '') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback
```

Here is `TestimoniesController`

```
class TestimoniesController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def index 
  end

  def show
    @testimony  = Testimony.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @testimony = Testimony.new(post_params)

    @testimony.save
    redirect_to @testimony
  end


  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:testimony).permit(:first_name, :email, :last_name, :contact_number, :country,    :question1, :question2, :question3, :question4, :question5, :signature, :waiver)
    end
end
```

Here is my Model file for `Testimony.rb`

```
class Testimony < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name,:email, :contact_number, :country, :question1, :question2, :question3, :question4, :question5, :signature, :waiver
  validates_uniqueness_of :last_name, :scope => [:first_name, :email]
end
```

I would like to display a message such as:
   Record already exists

Or
   All the fields need to be filled out

I realize this is pretty pathetic but I thought it was part of Rails magic to assert the uniqueness and presence of all of the fields of a Model at the form level, before you perform a @modelname.save. I clearly don't really understand. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `@modelname.save!` failed it'll raise an exception... the exception name varies depending on the orm you might be using. but most likely it'll be `ActiveModel::Validations`

you can use the following pattern i myself use

```
@testimony.save!
redirect_to @testimony
rescue_from ActiveModel::Validations do |ex|
  # here you can flash the message do what ever you want when saving fails
  render json: {message: 'Record already exists', status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

other solution is to use the following

```
if @testimony.save
  redirect_to @testimony
else
  render json: {message: 'Record already exists', status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

---

**[EXTRA INFO YOU CAN IGNORE :D]**

I use the first solution cause i can handle exceptions in the `application_controller`.

for example you can add those to the `application_controller` to handle those failing cases

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied, with: :render_access_denied
rescue_from Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound, with: :render_not_found
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :render_not_found
rescue_from(ActionController::ParameterMissing) do |parameter_missing_exception|
  error = {}
  error[parameter_missing_exception.param] = ['parameter is required']
  render_bad_request error
end
```

where `render_XXX` are methods defined in the application controller.

Comment: Thank you, but in the first solution how can I differentiate between whether or not a parameter is missing and whether or not the record exists? Is there a somekind of error value I can pattern match for?

Comment: check https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters and whether or not the record exists? if `@model.save!` passed then every is good and this is a new record. else there is something wrong and an exception is raised, this exception might be something you raised (custom exception you created) or validation or an exception raised from the model callbacks...

Comment: ah. so like when you write `ActionController::ParameterMissing` you are matching for that error, no? How can you catch the real version of something like `ActionController::DuplicateRecord`? I am having a hard time finding it in the Documentation.

Comment: I think what i was looking for was the following (which I apologize but you probably already answered) writing `format.xml { render xml: @testimony.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }`. or apparently writing `respond_with(@testimony)` which according to this page does the same thing: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html

Comment: IDK DuplicateRecord  may be [here] (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid), i don't work with `respond_with` and i don't know if they are the same...